# Spark - Number of executors and Number of servers

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera

I have a spark job which is really slow. when I go to the job history server UI in Cloudera I can see that the number of executors is just 2 along with a driver.

http://foo:18088/history/application_1456200816465_350138/executors/

but my cluster has 11 server in "commissioned" state for spark.

http://foo:7180/cmf/services/43/instances

So my question is why is my job using only 2 executors when there are 11 servers?

I ran my job from the command line

```
nohup spark-submit --class com.abhi.Foo --master yarn-cluster Foo-assembly.jar 
> output.txt 2> info.txt
```

Comment: Are you specifying the amount of executors when running your spark job?

Comment: obviously not @YuvalItzchakov :)

Comment: the default is set to 2 executors if you don't specify the num-of-executors explicitly either in spark-submit or while launching spark-shell

Comment: Than that shouldn't be too much trouble to fix :)

Comment: Friends. I can't thank you enough..... after I bumbed up the number of executors to 10..... it is multiple times faster. You guys are so awesome!!!!!